# laravel Sending values to blade

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm having a register form and login form on my home page

the login form is activated when you press the login link (via bootstrap)
and the register form is visible all the time

now when one off those fails, I wanna send the error's to the page
but I can only access the var's of these:

`return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator)
                         ->withInput(Input::except('password'));`

but when I add `->with('method', 'login')` I can't check in my home page the var $method
it's empty and never get's any values

can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?
and also how I can activate the login form with variables that I send with the `->with()`

the login form is made up like this:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm pvvoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login to your account</h4>
                </div>

                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/login', 'class'=>'form', 'role' => 'form')) }}
                <div class="modal-body">

                    @if ( $errors->first('username') != null || $errors->first('password') != null)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>Some errors occured</p>
                        {{ $errors->first('username') }}
                        {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
                            {{ Form::text('username', $value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Username', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus' )) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-asterisk"></span></span>
                            {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'password', 'required' => 'required')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => ' btn btn-primary')) }}
                    </div>

                </div>
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `with()` method flashes data to the session, you have to retrieve your data using `Session::get()`method.

Source : [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing it via AJAX :)
was easier for keeping the login form open